# Can not open the file as archive .pdf 7-Zip 16.04

Tags: pdf, cmd, 7zip

I have a .pdf file which I am able to open with Acrobat Reader DC.
I want to open this file with 7.zip by using the following command:

C:\Users\UserXY...\7z1604-extra\7za.exe t "C:\Users\UserXY...\Input2" -r

In the folder "Input2" I have a .docx file and a .pdf file both files can be opend without any issues by using Word or Acrobat Reader DC. How ever 7za.exe shows the following error if I try to open it via CMD:

"Can not open the file as archive"

See CMD extract below:

```
C:...\7z1604-extra\x64>7za.exe t "C:...\Input2" -r

7-Zip (a) [64] 16.04

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 folder, 2 files, 39360017 bytes (38 MiB)

Testing archive: C:...\Input2\PdfDoc.pdf
Can not open the file as archive


Testing archive: C:...\Input2\WordDoc.docx

ERRORS:
Headers Error
Unconfirmed start of archive


WARNINGS:
There are data after the end of archive

--
Path = C:...
Type = zip
ERRORS:
Headers Error
Unconfirmed start of archive
WARNINGS:
There are data after the end of archive
Physical Size = 26016386
Tail Size = 2054601

ERROR: Data Error : word\embeddings\oleObject2.bin

Sub items Errors: 1

Archives: 2
OK archives: 0
Can't open as archive: 1
Archives with Errors: 1

Warnings: 1

Open Errors: 1

Sub items Errors: 1
```

Question: How can I open .pdf with 7za.exe?

Comment: the `t` command in 7za verifies if the given file is a valid archive. How would a pdf file be a valid archive? It may work for docx, because a docx is essentially just a zipfile with a different extension.

Comment: A .pdf file is not a file format that 7-Zip can open. https://www.7-zip.org/ The `7za.exe` program supports less formats that `7z.exe`. What are you expecting to  find?